# Adding non apt-get packages to container-based infrastructure apt list

Tags: travis-ci, apt

I've opened up issues #[785](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/issues/785) and #[786](https://github.com/travis-ci/apt-package-whitelist/issues/786) to have [Luacheck](https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck) and [Busted](https://github.com/Olivine-Labs/busted) added the the travis-ci container system. However these are installed with Luarocks (which is already on the apt list).  The commands are `luarocks install busted` and `luarocks install luacheck`.  What is the process for getting packages like this installed on travis' container-based-infrastructure; as they require sudo to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to have a local install of luarocks as done by https://github.com/moteus/lua-travis-example. AFAIK, that's the only way to do that without sudo.

(FYI, those issues will fail as luarocks is a Ubuntu package as shown by http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=luarocks but Luacheck and Busted aren't)